# What tpl should I choose for this faq page?

Tags: 7, theming

What's the template that controls the /faq-page (from the FAQ Module in Drupal 7)?
I've read the explanation at the top of each tpl file inside the module, but can´t understand what file should I override.

**When I enter the /faq-page url, I have the categories. When I click each category, they open in a new page.
So I've tried the faq-category-new-page.tpl.php**

But it won't work. I've copied the tpl into my theme, opened it and added some css classes. They won't work (even when I've flushed cache).

What template should I choose? Thanks!
Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to copy all of the 9 templates from the module directory to your theme, and then add a simple output and see where and how they are used. You can later delete the ones you don't need to modify.

The templates used seems to be based on the configuration settings though, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I´lll just have to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Well, after grabbing the whole lot of default tpls, and adding at the bottom of each a print statement (and uploading to the server, and clearing cache), I can say that no, not any of them does affect the faq-page, nor any other page... (weird, but maybe I´m missing something here).

Comment: I´ve solved it customizing the theme from the css layer... I would rather change the tpl, but it seems there´s no other way?

Comment: If it doesn't work copying the templates to your theme and clearing the cache it's either something off with your Drupal install and/or your theme, or a bug in the module. First step in troubleshooting could be to make sure the caches are cleared by testing with other templates or checking the database tables.